# How do I easily store a file and folder location with argparse and then use those values

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I have Python module/script (depends what you read) I want to open a file and extract the contents to a directory, it works fine by using `file=sys.argv[1]` and `folder=sys.argv[2]` for example but I'd like to use argparse for ease of use for end users.

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Usage: '%s -h'" % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit(0)

def untar():
    #Both these values to come from argparse
    tarloc = tfile
    dest = folder

    #tarloc = sys.argv[1]
    #dest = sys.argv[2]
    filecount = 0
    tar = tarfile.open(tarloc)
    ....etc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Module to untar TAR files')
    parser.add_argument('-f', "--file", help='File to open', action="store_true", dest="tfile")
    parser.add_argument('-d', "--dest", help='Destination to extract to', action="store_true", dest="folder")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print args
```

Could someone please assist me with showing how you get argparse to store args and then how you use them.

Also should `argparse` be above or below the `if __name__ ==` section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your file and destination arguments are mandatory; if the user did not specify them your script would have nothing to do.

So don't use `-` or `--` options here, you want *positional* arguments:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Module to untar TAR files')
parser.add_argument('file', help='File to open')
parser.add_argument('folder', help='Destination to extract to')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Note that I removed the `action` arguments; `store_true` is for *boolean flag options*; e.g. if the user specifies the flag on the command line, something is switched on, no arguments are taken.

Next, pass those `file` and `folder` values to your function:

```
def untar(tarloc, folder):
    filecount = 0
    tar = tarfile.open(tarloc)
    # ....etc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Module to untar TAR files')
    parser.add_argument('file', help='File to open')
    parser.add_argument('folder', help='Destination to extract to')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    untar(args.file, args.folder)
```

You may want to follow the [`argparse` tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#argparse-tutorial) included in the Python documentation for more details.

Comment: Cheers, that did the job. The tutorial I've seen, some examples like yours would benefit that page...